# Why does insmod of a driver generate a ttyF device?

Tags: linux, drivers, serial-port, linux-device-driver

I've recently had the case of compilating a driver for a [PCIe to Serial Adapter](https://www.exsys.ch/de/pcie-karten/seriell/rs-232/2-port/pcie-2s-seriell-rs-232-karte-inkl-lp-buegel-oxford-chip-set1.html). (more specifically, the AX99100 chipset on that card)

For a quick test, I didn't really install the driver, but just used the `insmod` command to load the driver.

Upon looking into `dmesg`, I found it very odd that it generated `/dev/ttyF0` and `/dev/ttyF1` instead of `/dev/ttyS0` and `/dev/ttyS1`

I was wondering how that device name came to be?

Was this because of `insmod` or was this because of PCIe or maybe due to the operating system?

---

The driver worked just normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, `ttyS` **is not** the generic name for all serial ports – it is the name for 8250 UART serial ports on PCs, and similarly "built-in" serial ports on some other platforms.

So each driver decides on its own names when creating a device, and many drivers for "add-on" serial cards (which use various proprietary chips) deliberately select a different prefix to avoid mixups. In your case, the driver's authors have chosen to use `ttyF`.

(After all, the PCI card does not actually emulate a 8250 serial port. The OS sees it as a completely new and different device – which is why it needs a custom driver in the first place.)

Here are a few other examples that come built in with Linux (and that I found with 'grep'):

- ttyACM – USB serial adapters using the CDC ACM protocol
- ttyC – "Cyclades serial card"
- ttyEQ – "Equinox SST multi-port serial boards"
- ttyMX – "Moxa Intellio serial card"
- ttyUSB – USB serial adapters using other protocols
- rfcomm – Bluetooth RFCOMM serial port emulation

Comment: That explains a lot!